# ajaxStart/turbolinks:click are not fired when clicking on link using remote: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks-5

trying to show a spinner whenever a link with remote true is being clicked, tried both ways
using turbolinks:events and ajaxStart/ajaxStop events.
turboinks:load event is successfully fired, but :click isn't.
both ajaxStart and ajaxStop do not work.

Using rails 6, turbolinks 5, webpacker.
links are being generated in a very normal way
example:

```
<%=link_to 'Documents', documents_path, remote: true %>
```

this code is placed in `<head> </head>` of application.html.erb

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
     alert('turbolinks load works');
     //$(".sk-cube-grid").hide();
    });
    
    
    
    
      $(document).on("turbolinks:click", function(){
       alert('this doesnt work');
      //$(".sk-cube-grid").show();
    });
   
    </script>
```

code using ajaxStart/ajaxStop alternatively placed also in application.html.erb

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  alert('started ajax - doesnt work');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  alert('stopped ajax - doesnt work');
})
```

**EDIT**

changed the event handling to the following:

```
var page_loaded = function() {
  $(".sk-cube-grid").hide();
};


$(document).on("read page:load", page_loaded);

$(document).on("ajax:send", "a", function(xhr){
      $('.sk-cube-grid ').show()
}).on("ajax:complete", "a", function(data, status, xhr) {
  $(".sk-cube-grid").hide();
});
```

This code shows() the .sk-cube-grid when ajax:starts but not hidden when :complete nor when :success.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `remote: true` option tells Rails to use  [UJS (unobtrusive javascript)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) to handle the ajax. This is not handled by Turbolinks so the Turbolinks event you are listening to isn't fired.
You have two options: use UJS as you are [but listen to the correct event](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L66):  `ajax:success` or remove the `remote: true` and let Turbolinks handle it (and listen to `turbolinks:load` as you are doing now)

Comment: Sticking to remote: true, noticed that not all link_to with remote: true fire ajax:success, only methods to 'new' action.

Comment: maybe some of your actions are failing? they should all fire ajax:success. Anyway does this answer your question?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, ajax:success and ajax:complete are not being fired when clicking on a remote: true link. I tried to remove the remote: true, eventhrough turbolinks is enabled, clicking loads the page entirely instead of rendering .js.erb file that handles the modal (in my case).

Comment: I edited the question using a little bit different  code. Appreciated if you take a look.